# How to USB tether phone's internet to a Raspberry Pi 2 running Ubuntu Server?

Tags: networking, 20.04, usb, raspberrypi, tethering

I have installed Ubuntu Server 20.04 in my Raspberry Pi. I am trying to connect it to internet via USB tethering from my Android phone (and it does show up as `usb0` when I run `ip link`). Somehow the Raspberry Pi cannot access internet (I tried `sudo apt update` and `ping 8.8.8.8`, both failed).

In Raspberry Pi OS, the same Raspberry Pi works with the same phone.

How to use phone's USB tethering in Ubuntu Server?

Is there a package I can install to enable USB tethering? Then I can download that in another computer and install it offline.

Comment: Note that my Raspberry Pi 2 does not support WiFi, and I don't have access to an ethernet connection

Answer (score 0):

I've also been looking for answer to this question. Then I found the answer on https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Android_USB_tethering

If it already appears as usb0 when doing `ip link`, it's already a good sign, the last thing we need is to assign an ip address to that `usb0` by using `dhcpcd`.

To install `dhcpcd`:

```
sudo apt install dhcpcd5
```

Assign IP to `usb0` by asking the dhcp server:

```
sudo dhcpcd usb0
```

It should work now

Comment: I cannot connect to the internet (no WiFi, and USB tethering is not working), and that's why I cannot install it. Looks like I will have to download this package, and all its dependencies manually to install it.